# getting next date with 2019-03-23T18:30:00.000Z in angular/javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

why the below line returning the next date instead of supplied date
[image]

```
console.log(new Date('2019-03-23T18:30:00.000Z'));
```

but i need 23 march 2019 only.
Please provide a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's giving you the local time. Use toUTCString() for the desired output.

```
console.log(new Date('2019-03-23T18:30:00.000Z').toUTCString());
```

Comment: @Santhosh please note that depending upon what you pass as parameter while creating the new Date (i.e. 2019-03-23T18:30:00.000Z) the value will differ - if you are passing IST this solution might sound correct - but if that value is UTC then this will display incorrect value to end users in different timezone - say it differently someone viewing this value from say Europe instead of India will see Indian time and not Europe local time

Answer (score 2):

Please let me know how are you going to use it Angular so that I can help you. for example, in my case, the below helped.

```
   var d = new Date('yourDate');
   d.setMinutes( d.getMinutes() + d.getTimezoneOffset() );
```

'd' should be the correct date

Comment: You don't have to explicitly perform this if you are going to persist time in UTC - Javascript will automatically do this for you. Say it differently if "Your Date" is in UTC this conversion is automatically taken care by the browser engine. So input "Your date" in UTC format !!

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

> Creates a JavaScript Date instance that represents a single moment in
>   time. Date objects use a Unix Time Stamp, an integer value that is the
>   number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC.

btw UTC is behind IST and any local times of the east (say Asia/Japan/India etc) !!

Note that:

> If no arguments are provided, the constructor creates a JavaScript
>   Date object for the current date and time according to system settings
>   for timezone offset.

If this is not desired - you can convert you local time (perhaps you need IST) to UTC and then create an instance and convert this to IST and use it !

To say it differently, it is advisable to persist Date in UTC format on the server and let Javascript cast it for you depending upon the system's timezone(you need not cast it yourself manually)